# How to get the stabilization function working in Kdenlive?

Tags: 16.04, effects, kdenlive

I have a shaky video that I would like to stabilize with Kdenlive. However, I can't seem to get it to work. I right-click a clip in the project bin and select Clip Jobs -> Stabilize, but nothing happens.

[image]

I am using Kdenlive 15.12.3 on Ubuntu 16.04. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A [bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=360440) has been reported for this.

Comment: I think I found the bug and I submitted a patch upstream. We'll see where that goes.

Comment: Good news! [My patch was accepted.](http://commits.kde.org/kdenlive/96d863093774b4ec0ddaac69dfb0fd6c2a11732a)

Comment: What should happen when you do that? I'm using Ubuntu Studio 16.10, Kdenlive 16.04.3. When I perform this Clip Job, nothing happens.

Comment: Opened a new issue since I assume this bug to be fixed. https://askubuntu.com/questions/926563/how-to-stabilize-video-with-kdenlive

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug in Kdenlive 15.12.3. However, there is a newer version of Kdenlive out: version 16.04.1. This is the latest version of Kdenlive and the developers of the application have patched this bug in this version.

This should solve your problem. Good luck!

Comment: How is that possible? This problem was still present in the Git repository three days ago...

Comment: That's weird, I just googled around and a few websites have said that the bug was fixed in the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with 15.12.2 on Ubuntu 16.04. 
After reading here what TheChosenOne99 said, I made an update in Terminal (look here: https://kdenlive.org/download/) and the stabilization works now.

Comment: can you be more precise what commands shall we put in terminal?

Answer (score 1):

You have to **update** your kdenlive version. To check your current version type in terminal:

```
kdenlive --version
```

### To update your version

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kdenlive/kdenlive-stable

sudo apt update -y && sudo apt upgrade -y

sudo apt-get install kdenlive -y
```